# Images stopped showing on email notification after publishing new release

Tags: github

I have a private repository on Github where I have some colleagues watching so they get an email every time I publish a new release. Recently, when I publish a new release with images, they don't appear correctly in the email.

The only thing that shows is the following (example):
Image on email received
[image]

To insert the image all I do is (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd>). This would work in the older releases I made, but now it doesn't.
What I noticed is that the images link changed since the older releases I did, but still can't figure out how to make it work like it should:

- **Older releases link example:** ![image] (https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/...)
- **New Releases link example:** ![image] (https://github.com/RepoName/ProjectName/assets/...)

Any idea how I can make the images show correctly in the emails again?